# c# Runtime lose reference

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, system.reflection

I separated the Data Access Layer in my project to apply the different validations rules by countries.

**For example i have an interface "IVoucherService"**

```
public interface IVoucherService
{
    void Foo();
}
```

which implement in many Project

```
namespace VoucherHU
{
    [ApiLocalization(ApiLocalization.HU)]
    public class VoucherService : IVoucherService
    {
         public void Foo(){}
    }
}

namespace Voucher
{
    [ApiLocalization(ApiLocalization.US)]
    [ApiLocalization(ApiLocalization.DEFAULT)]
    public class VoucherService : IVoucherService
    {
         public void Foo(){}
    }
}
```

The following code determine which class has to be used

```
private static Type GetServiceImplementedType<TService>() where TService : class
{
    Type serviceType = typeof(TService);
    IEnumerable<Type> types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes()).Where(p => !p.IsInterface && serviceType.IsAssignableFrom(p));

    Type serviceImplementedClass = null;
    foreach (Type type in types)
    {
        ApiLocalizationAttribute[] attributes = (ApiLocalizationAttribute[])type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ApiLocalizationAttribute), true);
        if (attributes != null && attributes.Count() > 0 && attributes.Any(a => a.Localization == Localization))
        {
            serviceImplementedClass = type;
            break;
        }
    }

    return serviceImplementedClass;
}
```

**I register these services in the Global.asax -> Application_Start method.**
After publish it works fine, the services starts correctly, but if nobody use the website, the IIS (maybe to save resource) pauses the service until the next request. **When the API try to re register the services it could not find any class which implements the IVoucherService interface.**

**I checked it manually in the watch and i got the following error**

> Services.Voucher.VoucherService error CS0234: The type or namespace
>   name 'Services' does not exist in the namespace (are you missing an
>   assembly reference?)

and i got the same error for the other classes which implements this interface.

**Any idea why i loose the refference to these files (Services.dll, ServicesHU.dll)?**

Comment: Sorry but you don't seem to be a much of an upvoter here in Stackoverflow. There is very little point in providing answers to someone who has no habit of upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

### I figured it out.

Somehow the `AppComaing.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`no longer contains the assemly informations of the DLL files.

The solution was to refresh the referrenced assemblies on each time when Global.asax -> Application_Start method called.

To refresh the referrenced assemblies use this method

```
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies();
```